# Github Application Can't See How To Edit Files

Tags: git, bash, github

I've been searching the web for tutorials on how to effectively use the github desktop application I downloaded on my windows computer.. I didn't find much. More specifically, I want to be able to edit multiple files in the repository I copied from github, then upload/commit the changes in a single commit (for networking reasons).  I already found the button that merges branches within the desktop application, and I saw that it merged them on the website as well, which is good for when I finally figure out how to edit the files; however after clicking around in the limited gui I saw available, I can't seem to find any way to access/edit the files in said repository.

Here is a picture of what the desktop git-application looks like:  http://i.imgur.com/VlQSPTT.jpg

Maybe it's a git-bash/shell thing. Could you help me?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to be able to do this? I wouldn't think they were providing an editor just a git UI. So you should use your normal editor/IDE/whatever to make your changes.

Comment: Side note: you do not need to organize your changes in a single commit for networking purposes. Git shouldn't be doing anything network-oriented until you actually tell it to (e.g. to push your changes back to the remote repository). I suggest reading a few articles on writing effective commits, as they can be a great boon to a project.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it isn't meant to edit files..  I'll have to look into integrating it with my IDE somehow then.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be conflating Git with a source code editor.

It looks like you're using [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) which I do not believe includes any type of editor.

[Git for windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win) actually does include an editor - but it is Vi, which is not for everyone.

You want something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) to do your actual development in. Then use GitHub for Windows to commit any changes you make.

Comment: ...though if you're using Eclipse, it'll have its own, better-integrated git plugin.